# Is it possible to get ASCII font bitmap array just from a binary number?

Tags: c, bitmap, char

I'm looking for a solution where I can generate a 6*8 bitmap just from a binary number.

Assume that you were given the char `A` which is binary `0b01000001`. Is it possible for you to create a 6*8 bitmap (two colors only 0 and 1) from the letter `A` in C?

Or do I need to have a character set list such as this to find how the bitmap should be shaped?

[image]

Comment: What? You want to expand 7 bits of information into 48? Simply use an array of bitmaps and index it with the value of the character you want to display. *"Or do I need to have a character set list such as this"* -> yep!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, are you asking if the ascii number 65 (it of course doesn't matter if it's in binary or any other base, it's just a 7 bit integer) contains information about the shape of the letter A? Well then the answer to your question is no. You have to supply this information

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Thank you for your reply. So I need to have some kind of array with ASCII fonts?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes. I wonder how the LCD manufacturer factories does.

Comment: It is just an array of bit patterns - just a 2D version of 7 segment displays.

Comment: @MrYui they do exactly the same thing, just in a much more optimized way in hardware.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ok. Well, then I will look for an array that coveres all ASCII chars.

Comment: You're looking for a *character-cell bitmap font* in a format readily loadable into a C program.

Comment: Do you want hardware-specific OEM bitmap fonts, or to make up a new font, or to find a font on the internet that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you have to form a character map for each character.

Yet code can reflect your font design, tedious, but kinda fun.

```
#define MAP(s) ((s[0]=='*')<<5 | (s[1]=='*')<<4 | (s[2]=='*')<<3 | \
                (s[3]=='*')<<2 | (s[4]=='*')<<1 | (s[5]=='*')<<0)
static const unsigned char map[256][8] = {
  // ...
  // 2 examples
  // A
  { MAP( "  *** "),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *****"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( "      ") },
    // B
  { MAP( " **** "),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " **** "),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " *   *"),
    MAP( " **** "),
    MAP( "      ") },
    // ...
};
```

Various macros can wrap the initialization in an alternate manner as needed.

Comment: Very cute.  I'm reminded of the "westley" entry from the [1988 IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1988).